# Summation with indexed constants as an integral?

Tags: integration, summation

Is it possible to convert a summation with indexed constants to an integral?

Given the summation: $\sum^{n}_{i=1}C_ix^i $

My first thought would be to write $C_i$ as some function $f(i) = C_i$ resulting in the summation $\sum^{n}_{i=1} f(i)x^i$, but I am not sure how that would change the definition of the integral. Would the resulting integral be $\int^{n}_{1}\int^{i}_1f(i)*x \,di\,dx$ or something else?